# MONGODB faild connect

Tags: mongodb

Here's my log.

> C:UsersAdministrator>mongo MongoDB shell version v3.4.7 connecting to:
>   mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017 2017-08-16T23:45:23.316+0800 W NETWORK
>   [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0. :27017 after 5000ms
>   milliseconds, giving up. 2017-08-16T23:45:23.317+0800 E QUERY
>   [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to ver 127.0.0.1:27017, connection
>   attempt failed : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
>   @(connect):1:6 exception: connect failed

Comment: And what is your question? A little more detail would be nice

Comment: It means you are not actually running the `mongod` process. Read the [installation and usage instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) again carefully. They have lots of details and steps for a reason.